# What's the difference between devtool in webpack config file and other plugin's(e.g. UglifyjsWebpackPlugin) sourcemap option?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

As we know, webpack root config file provides the `devtool` option to set source map. But other plugins & loaders, e.g. UglifyjsWebpackPlugin, vue-loader, also provide the sourcemap option. What the difference between them? Overriding? Overlapping? Should we set both or just devtool?

Answer (score 0):

The webpack docs says:

> Instead of using the devtool option you can also use SourceMapDevToolPlugin/EvalSourceMapDevToolPlugin directly as it has more options. Never use both the devtool option and plugin together. The devtool option adds the plugin internally so you would end up with the plugin applied twice.

So it is not recommaned that ues them the same time.